# KML Heatmap for Google Earth or Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, kml, heatmap, google-earth

I have been given the task of making a **KML file** that can be dropped onto **Google Earth or Google Maps** and display the data as a **heatmap**. The script has to be written in PHP and generate a KML (xml) output. I have made some circles and such work but I am coming to what I think is a realisation that it can't be done after hours trying to work this out. Does anyone know if you can generate a `.kml` file that you can drag and drop onto google earth for example and it will display like a heatmap, similar to the below.

[image]

**I *can not* use any JavaScript** (or I wouldn't have this problem in the first place).

**Example single point KML file.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
        <Placemark>
        <name>Test Point</name>
        <description>Test Point Description</description>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>147.095947265625,-23.664650731631614,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
</kml>
```

Comment: I'm a little confused here. As I understand there is a web page, and you need to display a KML file with Google Map component in it. and you need to insert some javascript codes to load KML for Google Map. if you already have a PHP to generate kml file for you, and user going to drag KML into google map/google earth, then what is your task?

Comment: If you need to generate the KML, there is a libkml for that,  which have a python and Java binding. I really don't think it is a good idea to using PHP to do that.

Comment: Whether I use Python or Java isn't really the question. What I am trying to work out is if you can create a heat map with a KML file. I found a way to do it by creating a heatmap image with python and using it as an overlay. But is there a way to have a KML as a heatmap styled in xml?

Comment: For generating a heatmap, there is a python lib in pypi for that purpose. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/heatmap I think you are asking for a specific solution, not a question.

Comment: Have you looked at uploading the KML to [Google Fusion Tables](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2571232). It can display an interactive heatmap of the data.

Comment: @pingz yes this solution offers an image overlay, that has to be attached with the KML. I am asking if a heatmap can be done without using an image overlay, just using XML

Comment: @JasonM1 Google Fusion Tables takes the KML and uses JavaScript to interpret it. So this would be similar to using the Google API to interpret the code and render it using JavaScript

Comment: Can I style points using KML markup to display as a heatmap is my question OR can it not be done? (without an image or JavaScript)?